# Height setting from the embed or link code in Css

Tags: html, css

How to make height settings from the embed link for video background under the header, such as this website: https://www.videvo.net/, I own embed link video that is very responsive, and the change height in this link:`<div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:56.250%;"><iframe src="https://streamable.com/e/c1tb1o?autoplay=1&nocontrols=1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Remove padding-bottom and set the height and you should be good to go!

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100px;position:relative;">
<iframe src="https://streamable.com/e/c1tb1o?autoplay=1&nocontrols=1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the edit not good, please want help to change the height such as this website: videvo.net

Comment: @thoth Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height for more information.

Comment: I found the solution, on this website: https://pushlabs.co/#finding-your-container, when I inspected the page, I took a copy of the video link, but I want to help to modify the link like it.

Comment: The link video:<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/262914855?h=fa25729664&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;muted=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=1&amp;app_id=122963" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" title="NIKE TOKYO GO" __idm_id__="16400386" data-ready="true" style="width: 1903px; height: 1071px; top: -226.5px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;"></iframe>